# XCode weird bar

Tags: xcode

[image]

How could I remove this one???
I don't remember, how I have added this bar, likely I have pushed some shortcuts and it has appeared.
I tried remove xcode and reinstall it, but it does not help.
It prevents me from writing code.
Can I remove all the settings in XCode??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can a 40-60px bar prevent you from writing code?
I mean... seriously?

Comment: when I want to edit the code, it catches my events

Comment: ahhh, now that's a whole different thing, might it be a debugger?

Comment: What version of XCode is this?

Comment: Version 4.4.1
Can I remove all the settings in XCode?

Comment: https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim/
I decided it. It is the Xvim plugin))

Answer (score 3):

To reset Xcode to its factory settings for the logged-in user, run these commands in Terminal:

> defaults delete com.apple.Xcode
>   rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Xcode

Taken from [here](http://www.thejoeman.com/2010/05/how-to-reset-xcode.html)